# Having issues with hibernate running update queries right after select queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having issues with JPA (hibernate) select which is generating lots of update queries too. I have `@OneToOne` mapping between my entities.

I am also using following annotation on some of my getters method, not sure if they would make object dirty.

```
1.@Type(type = "yes_no")
2.@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
3.@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

Any idea in correct direction will be appreciated. My queries are returning collections.

Comment: Are you modifying the objects returned by the select query?? If yes, you must detach those objects from the EntityManager first; if not, the objects gets dirty and any changes are replicated to the database... to detach the objects you can use EntityManager.clear().

Comment: Looks like in some of my getter's I am manipulating instance fields to avoid NPE  when sending same object returned from DB to UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to detach the objects returned by the query first... use: `EntityManager.clear()`.

Comment: I accept this answer as It helped me to think in correct direction. For me this issue was resolved  simply by not modifying instance fields in getters .